# How to get tor on my iPhone 7

Tags: support

Want to get tor on my iPhone 7 where to go to download and how to properly download tor. I clicked the Mac download button and it gave two locations folder and iCloud Drive. Sent it and Tried to open in both but will not ope.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official Tor app that is developed by or maintained by the Tor Project. If you trust the Tor Project, that
does not necessarily mean you should trust arbitrary Tor apps you find in the iOS store. Maybe they work.
Maybe they are safe.

That being said, recently the Tor Project has [endorsed Onion Browser](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-heart-onion-browser-and-more-ios-tor), which is available on the App Store [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/onion-browser/id519296448?mt=8&at=10l9R4).